# Nexus 5x Won't Turn On

Tags: adb, power-on

My Nexus 5x started bootloading but now it won't turn on at all. I noticed the battery was bulging so I replaced it with a new battery I bought on Amazon. I charged it all night, but it still won't turn on. I've tried different key combinations and holding them for various times, still nothing. I plugged it into my computer, nothing. I installed ADB, and it didn't list my device when I typed `adb devices`

(I have not been able to get it into fastboot mode. If I had been able to, this question would not exist)

Is there any way to salvage my phone? If so, please help!

EDIT: There has been no indication of anything happening since the changing of the battery. i.e. no lights, no indication of charging, nothing at all.

Comment: Have you tried booting it to fastboot mode? (Press and hold the Power and Volume Down until the fastboot screen appears)

Comment: @IiroP, did you even read his question?

Comment: You say you charged it all night. Was there any indication that it was in fact charging?

Comment: I think the battery is dead (no charge), try changing it outside of the phone (check YouTube videos) then place it back to the phone, should power on now. ADB will never work on a phone that is not fully booted to android or in recovery mode. Try `fastboot devices` instead

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Well, he didn't mention exactly what key combinations he had tried. And I have once succeeded at booting phone to fastboot when it seemed to be dead.

Answer (score 0):

Your current phone state is bricked, You have two options

1. You have to flash official firmware using PC (In your case, your phone isn't even getting detected. You may need to install all drivers such as adb, properly and check it once again)
2. You have to go to authorized Service center to get this issue fixed.If you have warranty make this as first priority.